# Add RSS feed to a section of a View in Codeigniter

Tags: php, ios, codeigniter, templates, rss

I am completely new to Codeigniter and am trying to add an RSS feed to a section of my Home view as follows. I have asked this question already but I wasn't clear in how I presented my code so I have submitted it again. I have researched this on multiple forums especially this one and I am going round in circles but cant find an answer.

**Home View**

The home view contains a header image, a nav bar, a jumbotron and a login form. It also has the following section into which I want to add the RSS content.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-8"><h1>Latest News</h1>

<?php

// RSS FEED HERE

?>
```

I have one controller called "User that has the following code in its index function

**User Controller Code**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User extends CI_Controller{

public function __construct()
{

  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->model('user_model');
  $this->load->library('rssparser');

}

 public function index()
 {

  if(($this->session->userdata('user_name')!=""))
  {
   $this->welcome();
  }

 else
 {

 $data['title']= 'Home';
 $this->load->view('include/header',$data);
 $this->load->view('pages/home.php', $data);
 $this->load->view('include/footer',$data);

 }

}
```

**Controller method in User Controller to get RSS data**

The rss feed results are currently being stored in an unordered list

```
 public function get_news()
 {

 // Get 6 items from latest news
 $this->rssparser->set_feed_url('http://www.datadomain.com');  // get feed
 $this->rssparser->set_cache_life(30);  // Set cache life time in minutes
 $rss = $this->rssparser->getFeed(6); 

 echo '<ul>';

foreach ($rss as $item)

{
   echo '<li>';
   echo $item['title']; 
   echo '</li>';

   echo '<li>';
   echo $item['description'];
   echo '</li>';

   echo '<li>';
   echo $item['link'];
   echo '</li>';

   echo '<li>';
   echo $item['pubDate'];
   echo '</li>';
}   

echo '</ul>'; 
}
```

If I insert the following into my index function in my controller I can get the feed on my homepage but it appears at the top of the page and not in the section I need it in.

```
$data['rss'] = $this->get_news();
```

I have tried adding $rss into the section of the view in my Home page but I just get an undefined variable error.

I would appreciate if someone could help shed some light on this for me as I cant find a solution.

Other methods and views used in my project

**Controller method Welcome()**

```
public function welcome()
{
 $data['title']= 'Welcome';
 $this->load->view('include/header',$data);
 $this->load->view('pages/welcome_view.php', $data);
 $this->load->view('include/footer',$data);
 }
```

**welcome_view**

This view represents the members area of the application. It doesn't hold any real content at the minute because the application is at the early stages of construction.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<header class="page-header">
<img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo site_url('../images/black_header.jpg'); ?>"   /> 
</header>
</div>
</div>


<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">

 <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
 <div class="navbar-header">
 <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs- example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo site_url('user/index') ?>">Premier Games</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('user/index') ?>">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('user/register') ?>">Register</a></li>
  </ul>

  <p class="navbar-text navbar-right"><strong>Signed in as <?php echo $this->session->userdata('user_name'); ?></strong></p>

  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

  </nav>


  <div class="container">
  <div class="content">
  <h2><?php echo $this->session->userdata('user_name'); ?>, Welcome Back</h2>

  <p>This section represents the area that only logged in members can access.</p>

  <h4><?php echo anchor('user/logout', 'Logout'); ?></h4>

  </div><!--<div class="content">-->
  </div>
```

Comment: Please include `$this->welcome();` and the `views` you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you do the html parsing in a view. Not sure if you are loading a view... it isn't clear whether we are working with a logged in user or not.

Let's assume we are not dealing with a logged in user and are calling

```
 $data['title']= 'Home';
 $this->load->view('include/header',$data);
 $this->load->view('pages/home.php', $data);
 $this->load->view('include/footer',$data);
```

The easiest way to do it would be to just dump the data into the view and do the layout/parsing there:

controller:

```
$data['title']= 'Home';
$data['rss'] = $this->get_news();
$this->load->view('include/header',$data);
$this->load->view('pages/home.php', $data);
$this->load->view('include/footer',$data);
```

pages/home.php

```
<div class="container">
<?php
echo '<ul>';

foreach ($rss as $item)

{
   echo '<li>';
   echo $item['title']; 
   echo '</li>';

   echo '<li>';
   echo $item['description'];
   echo '</li>';

   echo '<li>';
   echo $item['link'];
   echo '</li>';

   echo '<li>';
   echo $item['pubDate'];
   echo '</li>';
}   

echo '</ul>'; 
?>
</div>
```

controller `get_news()`:

```
public function get_news()
{
    // Get 6 items from GAA latest news
    $this->rssparser->set_feed_url('http://www.rte.ie/rss/gaa.xml');  // get feed
    $this->rssparser->set_cache_life(30);  // Set cache life time in minutes
    $rss = $this->rssparser->getFeed(6); 
    return $rss;
}
```

Comment: We are dealing with a non logged in user. The latest news is on the home page of the application which is accessible to all users whether logged in or not.

Comment: OK, so this should explain it then.

Comment: That did the trick - thank you so much was at it for ages and driving myself mad trying to get it. Now just to format it to make it look good.